# Why is the webcolors library giving me an atribute error when the function is specified in the documentation

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a color mixer-calculator type thing that will tell you the color name based on the RGB code you input. As in the webcolor database there are no 256^3 color names (niether in real life, I think) I included aproximations to the colors that didn't have names to the nearest similar color. The problem pops out when using the

```
webcolors.cc3_hex_to_name
```

It raises an atribute error:

```
AttributeError: module 'webcolors' has no attribute 'css3_hex_to_name'
```

This is very strange as the webcolor's documentation clearly includes this atribute:
[Webcolors documentation extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg8MY.png)

Here's the whole code for reference:

```
import webcolors
webcolors.css3_hex_to_name
def closest_colour(requested_colour):
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items(): #Error line
        r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
        gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
        bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
        min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

def get_colour_name(requested_colour):
    try:
        closest_name = actual_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
    except ValueError:
        closest_name = closest_colour(requested_colour)
        actual_name = None
    return actual_name, closest_name

requested_colour = (119, 172, 152)
actual_name, closest_name = get_colour_name(requested_colour)

print ("Actual colour name:", actual_name, ", closest colour name:", closest_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES`